# read a plist generated with iso-8859-1

Tags: iphone, encoding, plist, iso-8859-1

I have created a plist using .net environment and after the creation I set the encoding type as "iso-8859-1" in the plist encoding type. Then I tried to read it and show in the table view. The values are not as expected.

It is having few characters which are of incorrect encoding type.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to load the file as an NSString, which you could specify an encoding.

```
NSString* plistString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:...
                                                 encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding 
                                                    error:NULL];
```

and then use [the `-propertyList` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) to convert the string into a plist.

```
id plist = [plistString propertyList];
```

---

But it is better to ensure you always generate UTF-8/UTF-16 on the C# side.

Comment: thanks for the code. But i still face problems. I opened that plist file with xcode, it had the character like this "Sjö" but when i used your code and tried that out for uitableview or nslog it shows as "SjÃ¶"what should i don ?

Comment: @thndrkiss: `"Ã¶"` = `c3 b6` in ASCII = `00f6` in UTF-8 = `"ö"`. Looks like the file is already in UTF-8.

Comment: great kenny. Excellent observation. I later found the same fact after a long time. thanks.

Comment: You mean Latin-1/Windows-1252, not ASCII.